# Zoom to see entire MapLayer in Bing Maps

Tags: mobile, silverlight, bing-maps, windows-phone

If I have a MapLayer that I'm applying to Bing Maps where I have a list of coordinates, how can I zoom to see the full MapLayer (dynamically zoom to the proper size) and toggle between seeing the starting point and ending point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setView(LocationRect rect)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.map.setview%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) in the Map to zoom. I would guess that [MapLayer.GetPositionRectangle(layer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.maplayer.getpositionrectangle%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) would give the full extent of the layer but I'm not sure. Otherwise loop through the list and create the LocationRect. For panning to different locations use the [SetView(GeoCoordinate center, double zoomLevel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588722%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) using the map [ZoomLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps.core.mapbase.zoomlevel%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The **BING Maps API - Interactive SDK for v7** is useful for finding out how the zoom to works

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#

The Zoom to Polygons seems to be

```
map.setView( {zoom:10}); 
map.entities.push(polygon);
```

Comment: That sample is for the Bing maps AJAX controls, the question was on the Silverlight WP7 controls... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955762.aspx