# Restricting zoom levels based on Bing Map availability?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, bing-maps

[My site](http://atlas.nsw.gov.au/public/nsw/home/map/base.html) is built on ArcGIS Server 10 with the JavaScript API 2.3, and uses Bing Maps as the background mapping. Although the site is aimed at NSW, Australia we allow the user to zoom anywhere in the world, at any of the supported scales (ie, the tiling scheme as specified in the [ArcGIS Help File](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//00930000006r000000.htm).)

Bing Maps road/satellite datasets are available at varying scale ranges, with [populated areas](http://t.co/FJqjDbJ) supporting larger scales than empty [rural areas](http://t.co/tDpgbQq). When zooming somewhere with no map/satellite data, a "broken camera" icon is shown. We'd like to avoid showing this ugly icon.

How can we restrict the maximum zoom scale where the map/satellite is not available, but allow full zoom-in where it is available?

Google Maps does this quite well - as you move around the world you can see the Zoom Slider expand/contract depending on what datasets are available at that location. They presumably have metadata showing the presence/absence of data, so we seek emulate this when using  Bing Maps, with no access to the metadata.

Comment: Use the Interactive SDK as in the previous post - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11285/zoom-to-see-entire-maplayer-in-bing-maps

Comment: Would that require rewriting my entire app in the Bing Maps SDK? If so, it's not really an option since this enhancement is a tiny "nice to have" feature

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @ElyFialkoff sorry, nope I never did solve this. These days I use the ArcGIS Server default basemaps, which seem to work better than Bing basemaps

Comment: @StephenLead I am pretty sure I came up with a solution I found somewhere else; for anyone else reading - I made a json request to the metadata, then looked at the start and end date, if these were `null` I assumed that the image is broken and request another image but with lower zoom values. Setting this up will be dependent on your language and set up (so I am not including my code).

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps is a tiled map, so has levels of detail when zoomed in or out.  I would fire a conditional statement on every extent change.
Something like:
event fired: Extent Change
Conditional: if map style = aerial and (get level < desired):
             set level back at desired...

Comment: Josh, this also looks promising- but how do I determine the value of "desired"? This will vary across the map

Answer (score 1):

Before zooming to a location, perhaps [get the image metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701716.aspx) to see what the finest resolution is available there.

> Determine the availability of imagery
>   at a location at a specified zoom
>   level

Since the response contains zoomMin and zoomMax, I suppose you could make the call just once at a low res zoom level and use the values from that, otherwise it seems like you might need to make multiple calls.

Comment: Kirk, this looks promising. A problem is that the returned ImageURL parameter may be valid, but show the "broken camera" icon I'm trying to avoid (eg http://ecn.t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a310311013120321331123.jpeg?g=689&mkt={culture}). I can't see how to "Determine the availability of imagery at a location at a specified zoom level" since the camera icon is technically "available"

Comment: Wow, that sure seems like a poor design decision.  Maybe if you convert the broken camera image to bytes then sum up the bytes you can know when you're zoomed too close.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMapServerMetadata(Url) {
    var metadata = "";
    esri.request({
        url: Url + "?f=json",
        handleAs: "json",
        callbackParamName: "callback",
        load: function (response, io) {
            metadata += "Map Name: " + response.mapName;
            metadata += "\n\nCurrent Version: " + response.currentVersion;
            metadata += "\n\nService Description: " + response.serviceDescription;
            metadata += "\n\nCopyright: " + response.copyrightText;
            metadata += "\n\nNumber of Layers: " + response.layers.length;
            metadata += "\n\nNumber of Tables: " + response.tables.length;
            metadata += "\n\nSpatial Reference: " + response.spatialReference.wkid;
            alert(metadata);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    });
}

// Available json objects
//        currentVersion
//        serviceDescription
//        mapName
//        description
//        copyrightText
//        layers
//        tables
//        spatialReference
//        singleFusedMapCache
//        tileInfo
//        initialExtent
//        fullExtent
//        units
//        supportedImageFormatTypes
//        documentInfo
//        capabilities
//        _ssl
```

e.g. try using the above code with a regular basemap MapServer url from ESRI like:
http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer

you can also use this on sublayers as well - to find out what metadata is there just use the base url and add ?f=json to have a json representation returned and iterate through the field names.

Comment: Hi Loran, welcome to GIS.se :) Please add a sentence or two above the code block describing it's purpose and what it does. Many readers won't be able to understand this with cursory review. (I'd also consider putting the list of json objects into columns so the code block doesn't take up as much screen real estate.)